# Efficient decoding a code dual to a Goppa code?

Tags: coding-theory, mceliece

Consider a matrix $H \in GF(2)^{a \times b}$ where $b > a$. This defines two linear codes. First, we have the code for which $H$ is the parity check matrix:
$$
C = \{ \mathbf{x} \in GF(2)^b | H \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0} \}.
$$
Secondly, we have the dual code, for which $H$ is the generator matrix:
$$
C^\perp = \{ \mathbf{y} H | \mathbf{y} \in GF(2)^a \}.
$$
For generic dense $H$, $C$ and $C^\perp$ are information-theoretically "good" error correcting codes in terms of rate and minimum distance, but the decoding problems for both $C$ and $C^\perp$ are computationally intractable. In a Goppa code, we know specific algebraic structure of $H$ which makes it feasible to decode $C$ by a polynomial-time classical algorithm. Does knowledge of this algebraic structure also enable us to efficiently decode $C^\perp$, or does decoding of $C^\perp$ remain essentially as hard as decoding a code with a generic dense generator matrix?

To be precise about "intractible" vs. "polynomial-time," the asymptotic family of problem instances I have in mind is the following. I imagine that the ratio b/a is fixed, the number of errors that we wish to decode is some (sufficiently small) fixed fraction of the bits, and we demand that our decoding algorithm have runtime scaling polynomially in $a$.

Comment: I have no deep knowledge on this topic. This paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.13038.pdf  seems to describe algebraic relationships between a Goppa code and its dual, not sure if it is of any help.